# Removing anonymous event handlers with some parameters

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I subscribe to an event like this:

```
private void CoupleOverlay(IMapVisual mapVisual)
{            
      overlay.DrawTilesProgressChanged += (s, e) => 
      {               
          mapVisual.DrawingProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
      };
}
```

The application may call CoupleOverlay event many times so I need to unsubscribe DrawTilesProgressChanged event and subscribe again but because it is an anonymous event I can't unsubscribe from it. I tried to convert to

```
private void CoupleOverlay(IMapVisual mapVisual)
{
    overlay.DrawTilesProgressChanged -=overlay_DrawTilesProgressChanged;                 
    overlay.DrawTilesProgressChanged +=overlay_DrawTilesProgressChanged;                 
}

private void overlay_DrawTilesProgressChanged(object sender, DrawTilesProgressChangedTileOverlayEventArgs e)
{       
    mapVisual.DrawingProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

It is not working because `mapVisual` is not valid variable on `overlay_DrawTilesProgressChanged` method.

If I change the code to

```
private void CoupleOverlay(IMapVisual mapVisual)
{
    EventHandler<DrawTilesProgressChangedTileOverlayEventArgs> drawEvent = (s, e) =>
    {           
        mapVisual.DrawingProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    };

    overlay.DrawTilesProgressChanged -= drawEvent;
    overlay.DrawTilesProgressChanged += drawEvent;
}
```

It will not work cause `drawEvent` is a local variable and next time I call CoupleOverlay, it will create new one.

So How can I unsubscribe from this event handler? Or how can I know I'm subscribed to the event so I don't need to subscribe again?

Comment: One solution is to make `drawEvent` a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: Why do you need to unsubscribe? Just subscribe and remove subscription on `Dispose()`.

Comment: @ IAbstract: I have a layer which has sublayers, first I call CoupleOverlay for all Sublayers and If user change the sublayers' definition, I need to call CoupleOverlay for all Sublayers again. the event is raising when drawing has progress, I just want to assign a number to progressPercentage of each SubLayer. the problem is that when I recreating sublayers because of this event GC can not remove the old-Sublayers from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it will not work cause drawEvent is local variable and next time I call CoupleOverlay, it will create new one.

Indeed. You'd basically need to keep an instance variable instead of a local variable. The instance variable would effectively be "the currently subscribed event handler". Then in `CoupleOverlay` you'd remove that event handler, create a new one (storing it in the variable) and resubscribing with it.

An alternative would be to use a single event handler, but keep the "current" overlay and map visual as instance variables, used by the event handler. The `CoupleOverlay` method would then just need to update those variables.

Comment: I called CoupleOverlay in loop like for() CoupleOverlay (,), so can you please give me basic sample of how to use a single event handler?

Comment: @Behnam: Well what are you trying to do within that loop? When is the event going to be raised, and how many bits of code do you want to be executed when it is?

Comment: I have layers which has sublayers, first I call CoupleOverlay for all Sublayers and If user change the sublayers' definition, I need to call CoupleOverlay for all Sublayers of that specific layer again. the event is raising when drawing has progress, I just want to assign a number to progressPercentage of each SubLayer. the problem is that when I recreating sublayers because of this event GC can not remove the old-Sublayers from memory.

Comment: @Behnam: It's still not really clear to me how many handlers you *want* to run when the event is raised. Think

Comment: I just simplifies the code a bit, consider in Photoshop you want to show the drawing progress in Layer manager per Layer/SubLayer, so we need to raise the event per Layer/Sublayer per draw progress.

Comment: @Behnam: So at any point do you know which layers and sublayers are active? If so, I don't see why you need another handler per layer/sublayer.

Comment: maybe I gave you a bad sample, the application is GIS application you have many Layers which each of them can have sublayers, when the user zoom in/out, the application start to redrawing the layers, so in layer manager we should show the percentage of drawing per layer/sublayer.

Comment: @Behnam: I'd rather not go too far into what your app does, but the important question is the one I asked before: do you know everything you need to update when the event is fired, regardless of which handlers are subscribed? If so, just use one event handler and look at which layers are visible.

Comment: Thanks  alot, I get your Idea, I'll try it tonight.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I unsubscribe from this event handler

You can not as lambda is a local variable and can not be acessed out of the scope where it's declared (in the function itself, in your case). To have a flexibility you required, you need to make use of `delegates`

> How can I understand I'm subscribed and event so I don't need to
>   subscribe again

To get the list of subsribers it's enough to make use of:

[MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) (events and delegates are multicast)